# Generate an "edit this document" link on all pages

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, blogdown, pkgdown

I really like the "Fork me on GitHub" banner in [`visNetwork`'s user manual](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/).

[image]

For [`pkgdown`](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown), [`bookdown`](http://github.com/rstudio/bookdown), and [`blogdown`](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) sites, is there a convenient way to generate such a link in the header of all pages?

Comment: The underlying files of the website are also on GitHub, as GitHub-pages are used. Maybe you find the banner somewhere in there: https://github.com/datastorm-open/datastorm-open.github.io/tree/master/visNetwork

Comment: Thanks, @Jannik Buhr. Found the HTML at https://github.com/datastorm-open/datastorm-open.github.io/blob/18e65c795a50c62ed1bc3fadde7e9e3963962fee/visNetwork/_includes/after_body.html. However, it looks like something they added manually, and the website itself was not generated by `pkgdown`, `bookdown`, or `blogdown`. I am looking for something more convenient, hopefully under those frameworks (particularly `bookdown`).

Comment: How is this an R question?

Comment: @42- `pkgdown`, `bookdown`, and `blogdown` are R packages that make it easier to build websites. I am asking if any of these packages specifically has a convenient way to supply a "Fork me on GitHub" link (or similar) to all pages. I plan on applying the solutions to https://ropensci.github.io/drake/ (generated with `pkgdown`) and http://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual (generated with `bookdown`). Both these sites are about an R package: https://github.com/ropensci/drake

Comment: Seemed like an HTML question, but i'll delete my comments in a bit.

Comment: It's okay, others may be wondering about the same thing.

Comment: Depending on the hugo-theme you are using with blogdown, you should be able to include custom html e.g. before the body